# Saying Shir Shel Yom at Mincha

Tags: mincha-afternoon-prayer, shir-shel-yom

It is my understanding that these three things (perhaps among others?) happened at the Mincha service:

- The daily Tamid ([Bamidbar 28:8](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm#8))
- The daily Ketores ([Shemot 30:8](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0230.htm#8))
- The shir shel Yom

Now, many people say the Tamid and Ketores at Mincha. The MB even writes it a good practice to do so.
(See MB and Mechaber here: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.234.6?with=all&lang=bi)

Why, then, should we not recite the Shir shel Yom with it, if you say those before Mincha?!

Comment: Do we know what song they sang at Mincha?

Answer (score 4):

The [Mishna berura 132:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.132.16?lang=en) explains that by Mincha it sometimes went into the night and they did not say the Shir:

> שחרית לבד - אף דבמקדש היו אומרים שירה על נסכי היין גם על תמיד של בין הערבים אכן מפני שכמה פעמים היו הכהנים טרודין והיו מביאין הנסכים של בין הערבים בלילה ובלילה אין אומרים שירה לפיכך נוהגין לומר השיר בשחרית לבד.

The [Aruch Hashulchan 133:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.133.2?lang=en) gives a different explanation, that sinces it is only as a remembrance, once a day is enough:

> ואחר כך אומרים שיר של יום, לזכר שיר הלוים בבית המקדש. ובמנחה לא נהגו לאמרו אף על פי שגם בתמיד של בין הערבים היו אומרים שיר בבית המקדש. ומשנה מפורשת היא בשלהי ראש השנה שפעם אחת נתקלקלו הלוים בשיר, ועל בין הערבים קאי, עיין שם. מכל מקום כיון שהוא זכר בעלמא – דיו בשחרית.

Comment: The Mishna Berura's answer has a big downside, namely that we also don't sing the song of Musaf

Comment: @double AA the Mishna Berura's source is the Magen Avraham. He adds a little more explanation there but at the end he finishes off with this. ובכ"ה כ' מנהגינו שביום שיש מוסף אומרים שיר של יום אחר שחרית ואחר מוסף אומר שיר של מוסף (מ"ע סי' כ"ה):